How do you get the datatype from a pointer to a datatype with decltype?
The decltype operator when used with a type* retutns type&. is there a way to get just the type.
int* i;
decltype(*i) l; // int& l;

int o; // decltype(???) o;

I just wanted to know if there is a way to do tht, do I need a library or something like that?
edit:
I originally didn't want to use any libraries but I would if i have to and I did try to find other questions to fix the problem but didn't find any that helped. I'm sorry I didn't properly mention that.

Does this answer your question? Remove reference in decltype (return T instead of T& where T& is the decltype)

Your use of decltype is not just some id-expression in the operator, so the usual rules of decltype apply:

If decltype is applied to an lvalue, the type is T&. (Your case)
If decltype is applied to an xvalue, the type is T&&.
If decltype is applied to a prvalue, the type is T.

See also What is decltype and how is it used?
How you approach this problem is up to you, and depends on the specific situation.
Here are some options:

std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(i)>
std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*i)>
decltype(auto(*i)) (C++23)


Observe:
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

template <typename T> void print()
{
    std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int* i;
    print<decltype(*i)>();
    print<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*i)>>();
    print<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(i)>>();  // works, even if not a reference
}

stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp && ./a.out
int&
int
int*

I just added the last line to show that you can remove_reference from a type that's not actually a reference.

You can use std::remove_reference, eg:
#include <type_traits>

int* i;
decltype(*i) l; // int& l;

std::remove_reference<decltype(l)>::type o; // int o;
// or, in C++14 and later:
std::remove_reference_t<decltype(l)> o; // int o;


A simple way is to write
#include <type_traits>

//...

std::decay_t<decltype( *i )> l;

